# How to programmatically get all the modules included in Play

Tags: playframework

I am trying to write a tag in my parent application(running play-1.2.4), which will detect all the included modules and create  tags for all the js files in the modules. Is this possible? Can I programatically get all modules that have been included in the parent application?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to get all Plugins, you can use `Play.pluginCollection`. If you want to get all modules, `Play.modules` is where you want to go